# Matlab and Mountain Lion

Tags: matlab, osx-mountain-lion

I have the 2012a version of Matlab and recently upgraded my Mac OS to Mountain Lion.

Having following the official instructions http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-IXBVKD/ 
the Mac now has XQuartz installed.

Despite this however, when I try to launch matlab either by clicking on the icon or by open an xterm window and typing .../bin/matlab, I don't have a successful launch.

In both instances, the Matlab icon shows up on the dock for a moment, then closes.

Any suggestions?

===============

(The following posts are on the same topic, but different varieties of the problem:

[Matlab on Mountain Lion not working -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781400/matlab-on-mountain-lion-not-working)

[Getting Matlab's mex to work with xcode 4.4 on Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745881/getting-matlabs-mex-to-work-with-xcode-4-4-on-mountain-lion) 
)

Comment: I had no problems with ML, just installed XQuartz and it worked perfectly. Did you restart you computer? Is XQuartz set as your default X11 environment?

Comment: I did restart my computer. How do I set XQuartz to be the default X11 environment?

Comment: That is, what beyond installing XQuartz do I have to do to set it to be the default X11 environment?

Comment: Check [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/how-can-i-change-default-x11-application) out. Might be helpful.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-IXBVKD/

Comment: Yes, those are the instructions I followed to the letter without success. I've submitted a service request to Mathworks. If I learn anything useful I'll post it.